# how to get input type text value? in jquery

Tags: jquery

This is just simple code but not working..

why not working...?? I'm confuse..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <h3> Hello Web</h3>
        <br>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" />
    </body>

</html>
```

<--! jquery -->

```
function hello(){
    $var=$('#textvalue').val();


    alert($var);

}
```

Comment: `why not working...??` Please elaborate the details on the issue you are facing.

Comment: What you are trying to do? and when it is not working?

Comment: ok.. i want on click submit button , get text type value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html should contain a button

```
<input type='button' id='btnSubmit' value='submit'>
```

it jquery should be like this

```
$("#btnSubmit").on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
hello();
}
```

Comment: `$var` in the question could be a global variable. Also, OP has not specified what is the issue.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas in this context it does not look like a global variable, Maybe he has not imported jquery properly.

Comment: oh! ok.. but. not working... i want button click and alert in get text data.

Comment: @koboso You may have to edit the question because what you are expecting isn't clear.

Comment: could you add <form> tag??

Comment: Only the issue is Dollar($) sign before value variable

Answer (score 0):

change 
`var value = $('#textvalue').val(); 
alert(value);`

Comment: `$var` in the question could be a global variable. Also, OP has not specified what is the issue.

Comment: i think it is not a global variable or maybe he forgot "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"

Answer (score 0):

The script must be connected at the end of the body.

```
<body>
<input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" />
<script src="js.js"
<body>
```

And where do you call the function hello()?

Comment: @koboso if this post helped you might think accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Place the above line of code in head and than try. it will work..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function hello(){
    $var=$('#textvalue').val();


    alert($var);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="hello()" value="SAVE" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code was not working is you did not call you function `hello` at any event.

You should not write as below

```
<head>
   <h3> Hello Web</h3>
   <br>
</head>
```

It should be like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="test-form" action="someurl" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> Below is the solution for your problem.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#test-form').submit(function(event) {
    // Prevent form submission
    event.preventDefault();
    
    alert("Form submission prevented");
    
    var textValue = $('#textvalue').val();
    // Alert the value
    alert("textValue = " + textValue);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="test-form" action="someurl" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="textvalue" id="textvalue" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" />
</form>
```